# How to build a mozilla firefox NSAPI sample plugin with only Gecko-sdk on linux

Tags: linux, firefox, plugins

I have built the gecko-sdk NSAPI sample plugins on Windows (using visual studio project files), but I would like to develop some plugins on linux platform.

The mozilla site only covers setting up gecko-sdk for windows:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Creating_XPCOM_Components/Setting_up_the_Gecko_SDK

However, the gecko-sdk code only includes a makefile.in file (no configure.in/ac/am that autoconf needs to generate a configure script).

I know that I can create the plugins Makefile if i build using full mozilla-source (firefox source)and I add the plugin directory to MAKEFILE_plugins in mozilla/toolkit/toolkit-makefiles.sh

then do a ./configure at top level.

But how do i do it for gecko-sdk?

Heres the plugin code:

http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/modules/plugin/

How do I build the samples on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an answer, more of a similar-but-different problem that might help you out.

Awhile ago I built a C++ XPCOM extension on OS X, and I didn't (have to) use the configure/Makefile from gecko-sdk. Rather, I just called GCC in [my own little Makefile](http://github.com/vasi/firefox-dock-progress/blob/433e98762b020b17abf10b36aafaa59c1094537b/src/Makefile).

The only thing to watch out for is to use the compatible compiler and build flags. You can look at a build log for firefox for your distro to figure out what build flags are appropriate, eg: [for Ubuntu](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/22018527/buildlog_ubuntu-jaunty-i386.firefox-3.0_3.0.6%2Bnobinonly-0ubuntu1_FULLYBUILT.txt.gz).